# Pacman is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyPressed(KeyEvent) in KeyListener. How do i fix this problem?

Tags: java

```
 class Pacman extends  JFrame implements KeyListener {
char pacmanShape = 'R';
char direction = 'R';
final int WIDTH = board[0].length * 30, HEIGHT = board.length * 30;
JPanel boardPanel;

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

 public void keyPrssed(KeyEvent e) {
  int Key = e.getKeyCode();
if (Key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
  direction = 'L';
if (Key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
  direction = 'R';
if (Key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
  direction = 'U';
if (Key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
  direction = 'D';
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public Pacman() {
super(" Review of Grade 11 class");
buffer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
// Set up the board
boardPanel = new JPanel();
boardPanel.setDoubleBuffered(true);
boardPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
boardPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

JPanel pane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
addKeyListener(this);
pane.add(boardPanel);
pane.add(boardPanel);
pane.setDoubleBuffered(true);
setSize(WIDTH + 40, HEIGHT + 40);
pack();
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I'm making a pacman game for a project. What mistake am i making? How can i fix this problem?

"Pacman is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyPressed(KeyEvent) in KeyListener."

Comment: Well, I'd first recommend checking your spelling and checking [How to Write a Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html); but `KeyListener` has known issues and you should be using the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Comment: `public void keyPrssed` is not a method of KeyListener.  This is why it’s good practice to annotate implemented methods with `@Override`.